# Need help in converting table formatted string to json response

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I am looking for help in shell script to convert a below table formatted string to json response.

```
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│                         │            executed │             failed │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│              iterations │                   1 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│                requests │                  24 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│            test-scripts │                  48 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│      prerequest-scripts │                  28 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│              assertions │                  44 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────────┤
│ total run duration: 8s                                             │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ total data received: 8.02kB (approx)                               │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│average response time: 144ms [min: 33ms, max: 806ms, s.d.: 198ms]
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

as

```
{
  "iterations": {
    "executed": "1",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "requests": {
    "executed": "30",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "test-scripts": {
    "executed": "60",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "prerequest-scripts": {
    "executed": "38",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "assertions": {
    "executed": "56",
    "failed": "0"
  },
  "total run duration": "8.9s",
  "total data received": "8.19kB (approx)",
  "average response time": "144ms"
}
```

I am looking for a shell script like some jq command as Ruby will not work in my environment. can someone help me on this

I have tried to remove special character and recreate the string but I am unable to achieve my expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a different approach, also using `awk`:

File script.awk

```
BEGIN { printf("{\n") }
/iterations/ || /requests/ || /test-scripts/ || /prerequest-scripts/ || /assertions/ {
    printf("  \"%s\": {\n", $2)
    printf("    \"executed\": \"%s\",\n", $4)
    printf("    \"failed\": \"%s\"\n", $6)
    printf("  },\n")
}
/total run duration/ {
    printf("  \"%s %s %s\" \"%s\",\n", $2, $3, $4, $5)
}
/total data received/ {
    printf("  \"%s %s %s\" \"%s %s\",\n", $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)
}
/average response time/ {
    printf("  \"%s %s %s\" \"%s\"\n", $2, $3, $4, $5)
}
END { printf("}\n") }
```

File script.bash

```
#!/bin/bash

awk -f script.awk table.txt
```

- To execute, run `./script.bash` (or call the awk command directly like in the bash).
- table.txt contains your table.
- For "average response time", I assumed it was missing from the sample input you have in your question, so I added it in my table. (average response time: 234ms) in the empty line you have in your sample.
- If "average response time" is calculated from the above data, you will have to include how to do it in your question.
- The output is:

  ```
  {
    "iterations": {
      "executed": "1",
      "failed": "0"
    },
    "requests": {
      "executed": "24",
      "failed": "0"
    },
    "test-scripts": {
      "executed": "48",
      "failed": "0"
    },
    "prerequest-scripts": {
      "executed": "28",
      "failed": "0"
    },
    "assertions": {
      "executed": "44",
      "failed": "0"
    },
    "total run duration:" "8s",
    "total data received:" "8.02kB (approx)",
    "average response time:" "234ms"
  }
  ```

Comment: thanks for the script, it worked, I would help in tweaking the script to handle average response time some times I would get the response as `average response time  : 145ms` or as  `average response time  : 145ms [min: 30ms, max: 845ms, s.d.: 211ms]`, can you help me with script handle the both scenarios

Comment: Everything is based on your input data.  If the input data contains more for the average response time, you can modify the code for that particular line.

Comment: @Nic3500, can we have the script the same shell file rather a new awk file and call it? something like below

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN { printf("{\n") } /iterations/ || /requests/ || /test-scripts/ || /prerequest-scripts/ || /assertions/ { printf("  \"%s\": {\n", $2) printf("    \"executed\" : \"%s\",\n", $4) printf("    \"failed\" : \"%s\"\n", $6) printf("  },\n") } /total run duration/ { printf("  \"%s %s %s\" : \"%s\",\n", $2, $3, $4, $5) } /total data received/ { printf("  \"%s %s %s\" : \"%s %s\",\n", $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) } /average response time/ { printf("  \"%s %s %s\" : \"%s\"\n", $2, $3, $4, $5) } END { printf("}\n") }' logs.txt > Response.json`

Comment: Yes it can be all in one file

Answer (score 1):

We can imagine a solution using only `bash`.

The table example suggests these for the **JSON** values:

- `object` and `array` is not something that would need to be handled.
- whereas the rest of possible values should be handled: `string`, `number`, `null`, `true`, `false`

Give this a try:

```
formatted_string='
┌─────────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬────────────────────┐
│                         │            executed │             failed │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│              iterations │                   1 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│                requests │                  24 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│            test-scripts │                  48 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│      prerequest-scripts │                  28 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼────────────────────┤
│              assertions │                  44 │                  0 │
├─────────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴────────────────────┤
│ total run duration: 8s                                             │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ total data received: 8.02kB (approx)                               │
├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ average response time: 267ms                                       │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘'

declare -a names
names+=(" ") # not used: "trick" to force idx integer below to be directly useable with names arrray
let object_count=0
printf "{\n"
while IFS= read -r line ; do
  if [[ ! "${line}" =~ [[:alnum:]] ]] ; then
   continue
  fi
  if [[ "${#names[@]}" -eq 1 ]] ; then
    while IFS= read -r value ; do
      if [[ "${value}" =~ [[:alnum:]] ]] ; then
        names+=($(printf "%s" "${value}" | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//'))
      fi
    done < <(printf "%s" "${line}" | sed 's/│/\n/g')
  elif [[ "${line}" =~ 'total run duration' ]] ; then
    line="${line##*:}" ; line="${line# *}"
    printf ',\n  "total run duration": "%s"' "${line%% *}"
  elif [[ "${line}" =~ 'total data received' ]] ; then
    line="${line##*:}" ; line="${line# *}"
    printf ',\n  "total data received": "%s"' "${line%% *}"
  elif [[ "${line}" =~ 'average response time' ]] ; then
    line="${line##*:}" ; line="${line# *}"
    printf ',\n  "average response time": "%s"' "${line%% *}"
  else
    let idx=0
    while IFS= read -r value ; do
      if [[ "${value}" =~ [[:alnum:]] ]] ; then
        value=$(printf "${value}" | sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//;s/[[:blank:]]*$//')
        if [[ idx -eq 0 ]] ; then
          if [[ $object_count -gt 0 ]] ; then
            printf ",\n"
          fi
          printf '  "%s": {\n' "${value}"
          idx=$((idx+1))
        else
          if [[ $idx -gt 1 ]] ; then
            printf ",\n"
          fi
          printf '    "%s": ' "${names[$idx]}"
          if printf "%f" "${value}" 2>/dev/null >/dev/null || [[ "${value}" == true ]] || [[ "${value}" == false ]] || [[ "${value}" == null ]] ; then
            printf '%s' "${value}"
          else 
            printf '"%s"' "$(printf "%s" "${value}" | sed 's/\(["\]\)/\\\1/g')"
          fi
          idx=$((idx+1))
        fi
      fi
    done < <(printf "%s" "${line}" | sed 's/│/\n/g')
      printf "\n  }"
      object_count=$((object_count+1))
    fi
done < <(printf "%s" "${formatted_string}")
printf "\n}\n"
```

the output is:

```
{
  "iterations": {
    "executed": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "requests": {
    "executed": 24,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "test-scripts": {
    "executed": 48,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "prerequest-scripts": {
    "executed": 28,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "assertions": {
    "executed": 44,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "total run duration": "8s",
  "total data received": "8.02kB",
  "average response time": "267ms"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using AWK.  Learn from the many internet examples.  This script gets you close:

```
BEGIN           { h["│"]; h["total"]; h[""] }
/total run/     { labelC=$2 " " $3 " " $4; valueC=$5 }
/total data/    { labelD=$2 " " $3 " " $4; valueD=$5 " " $6 }
                { if ($2 in h) {} else { executed[$2]=$4; failed[$2]=$6 } }
END     { print "{"
          for (x in executed) { print "\"" x "\": {\"executed\": \"" executed[x] "\", \"failed\": \"" failed[x] "\"}," }
          print "\"" labelC "\": \"" valueC "\","
          print "\"" labelD "\": \"" valueD "\","
          print "\"average response time\": \"unknown\""
          print "}"
        }
```

Save the script as "format.awk" and run AWK against your input.txt file, like this:

```
% awk -f format.awk input.txt
{
"iterations": {"executed": "1", "failed": "0"},
"requests": {"executed": "24", "failed": "0"},
"assertions": {"executed": "44", "failed": "0"},
"prerequest-scripts": {"executed": "28", "failed": "0"},
"test-scripts": {"executed": "48", "failed": "0"},
"total run duration:": "8s",
"total data received:": "8.02kB (approx)",
"average response time": "unknown"
}
```